# Contour integration of $\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\sin z}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to evaluate the contour integral $\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\sin z}{z}$ around the unit circle counter clockwise. My method is to use the Taylor Expansion of $\sin z$, which then leads to the integral of the sum of powers of $z$, so the integral is 0. Similarly I evaluate $\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\cos(z^2)}{z}$ and conclude that it's equal to $2\pi i$ as the powers of $z$ vanish.

Am I correct?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Residue theorem? It would be more direct. Your method requires justification for an integral of an infinite sum.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that theorem, I don't think we covered that yet

Comment: This is a direct application of Cauchy integral formula, $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin z}{z-0} \:dz = 2\pi i \sin 0$$

Comment: Ah yes, thanks!